# Error messages trying to build Julia language with make

Tags: github, makefile, julia

This is the first time I have every used `make`.  I am trying to install the Julia language.   So I cloned from GitHub

```
git clone git://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
```

The instructions then say enter in the `Julia` directory and type `make`.  It ran for a very long time - I ate a pizza.

When I got back, typing `Julia` did not work.  Towards the end of the installation, I got a long error message:

```
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libpcre.pc libpcreposix.pc libpcrecpp.pc '/home/john/Downloads/julia/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   130  100   130    0     0    243      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   337
  0     0    0 8773k    0     0   310k      0 --:--:--  0:00:28 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transferred the last 15 seconds
curl: (6) name lookup timed out
make[2]: *** [openblas-v0.2.8.tar.gz] Error 6
make[1]: *** [julia-release] Error 2
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

I tried `sudo make` - putting `sudo` in front seems to solve everything but not this:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
make[2]: *** [openblas-v0.2.8/config.status] Error 2
make[1]: *** [julia-release] Error 2
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

What steps can I take to makes sure Julia installs properly?

I need version 2.0 so I can use [iJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) with my iPython notebook.  If there is an easier way without compiling directly, I would just do that.

Comment: "Putting sudo in front" of everything, particularly things where you don't know what they do, is an _extremely_ bad idea.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Usually, it's because I forgot to put `sudo` in front of `pip install xyz` to install a Python library.  Or `apt-get install xyz`.  But today I am learning Julia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the makefile is trying to download a file (`curl` is a command line program that acts like a web browser, and is often used to download files from websites).

However, for whatever reason (maybe the internet was tired) the download failed and timed out.

The reason it fails now with the *unexpected end of file* error is that (a) the download gave you part of a file before it failed, and (b) the makefile you're using is badly written so it didn't clean up the partly-downloaded file on failure.

So, that file exists and thus make won't try to download it, but it's only partial so when you try to uncompress it, it fails.

You should delete the file it tried to download by hand (with something like `rm -f openblas-v0.2.8.tar.gz`) then re-run make.  Maybe the internet has woken up, or drunk some coffee, and the download will work this time.

Comment: `rm -f deps/openblas-v0.2.8.tar.gz` took a real long time - worked like a charm